# Leave value in the input even if Ajax call doesn't return any results in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using the Select2 plugin as an autocomplete for a input box. The autocomplete makes an Ajax call and everything is working great except when the there is not results then I'll like to leave the value as is and that does not work. For example: if I type "555" and that value wasn't found on the Ajax call then I want to leave "555" as a the text value since I'll hit a button later for add it.

This is my code:

```
if ($codigo_arancelario.length > 0) {
    $codigo_arancelario.select2({
        placeholder: "Seleccione un estado",
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'json',
            url: function () {
                var codigo_arancelario = $codigo_arancelario.val();
                return Routing.generate('obtenerCodigoArancelario');
            },
            data: function(codigo_arancelario) {
                return {
                    filtro: codigo_arancelario
                }
            },
            results: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data.entities
                };
            }
        },
        formatNoResults: function () {
            return "No se encontró el código";
        },
        formatAjaxError: function () {
            return "No hay conexión con el servidor";
        },
    });
}
```

Here is a visual example:

[image]

What else I need to do in order to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe this will help in your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466788/select2-ajax-search-remember-last-results

Comment: @Wado not, it doesn't help it's totally different what it need from what I need, take a look to the image I leave, maybe this clarify a bit my question

Comment: @ReynierPM, was my edit / answer at all helpful? a little more info and Ill try to better my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not handle for this with the response, if the response has no data return the original value used to query for data?

Per request, here is a snip of what it could look like if you were using C# and EF to search a DB for results. Please keep in mind this is a very simple example of what it could look like not knowing anything about the service you are hitting with your AJAX call.

```
    var searchResult = db.Where(x=> x.somethingToSearchAgainst == searchPeram);
    return searchResult.length == 0 
        ?   searchPeram
        :   searchResult;
```

Comment: @ReynierPM i could but not sure what you your code looks like. you would handle this on the server side. what ever Routing.generate('obtenerCodigoArancelario'); method is. if you can add that code i can give you an example. Will edit this to show as if it were done in c# but not sure what you are using

Comment: Yes I get the whole idea is not pretty much what I was looking but seems to be work, I'll test later

Comment: @ReynierPM, good news. you could do something similar on the js side of things when handling the results before you return data.ent